# Are there any easter eggs on Contra Hard Corps?

Tags: contra

I was playing Contra Hard Corps on my Genesis 16 bit these days, and finished it in all possible ways, first going to the research center, etc.. In any possible way I could finish it, I finished.

However, I like this game a lot, and I was thinking, are there any "easter eggs" in this game, maybe some hidden mission that you could tell me where to find.

Comment: I've removed the gensis tag from your question. We reserve the use of platform tags when a question is about that platform, or a games interaction with that platform. There is a [relevant meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/platform-tags-are-useless) topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 6 ending in total: 4 "regular" endings that you get for following 3 route splits (one at start and then one more split on each branch), a "bad ending" if you agree to join Colonel Bahamut when offered this choice before his boss battle and secret "prehistoric age" ending, if you climb up the wall before Noiman Cascade (the hacker)'s boss room.

None of 2 special endings add additional full missions. Bad ending just ends game right after you choose to join. Prehistoric age, however, gives you several bonus boss fights in quick succession, much like Noimans's fight would.